# Who is responsible to set the To header (Ws-Addressing) in an outgoing message?

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm creating a transport binding in WCF, and I've seen that outgoing messages of my output channel don't have the To header set (WS-Addressing).
I don't really want to add yet another responsability to my transport channel. Do you know a behavior or binding which takes care of that for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, that responsability may fall on the transport channel, though channels in layers above that could potentially mess with that. Best option would be simply to use EndpointAddress.ApplyTo(message) to make sure it gets filled.